# Apache SSI and XML

Tags: xml, apache, ssi

I'm trying to show or hide some xml using Apache Server Side Includes logic when viewing in a browser:

```
<!--#config timefmt="%Y%m%d%T"-->
<!--#if expr="($DATE_LOCAL < '2011071709:20:00')"-->
<xml>...</xml>
<!--#endif -->
```

However, this fails, it treats the ssi statements as comments (I see them in "view source").

The SSI page in the apache documentation states this only works with HTML but wondering if anyone has managed to get this to work with xml pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache looks at the file extension to decide whether to parse the SSI statements. It won't work with .xml files unless you configure it in the http.conf , or in an .htaccess file.

Comment: Thanks Breton, you are right.  I went ahead and added the following to the directory config:      AddType application/xml xml
                           AddHandler server-parsed xml